# How are the piano keyboard and performer fingers lit in Synthesia cover videos?

Tags: piano, software

[Here's one of many videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sbTVZMJ9Z2I) created using Synthesia music visualization software. The upper part of the screen looks like it's drawn by the software. The lower part looks like it shows a real piano and real performer hands shot on camera.

How does it happen that as "bricks" approach the piano keyboard the keyboard and the hands are being illuminated by light of the same color and matching intensity as if the "bricks" were real and actually emitted light?

Comment: This sounds more like a question for video editing than music practice and theory.  If this is more about music in your eyes, I think we'll need to have some sort of additional context as to why.

Comment: I'd guess that random video editor people would have much lower chance of knowing the answer compared to random music performers.

Answer (score 4):

When people like [Rousseau](https://www.youtube.com/rousseaumusique) record their videos, they have a specific lighting pattern setup on their keyboard so the LEDs at the top of the keys light up when pressed, and at the same time as they record the playing with the lights, they record the MIDI and throw it into a Synthesia file or some other software. Then they just overlay it on top in editing.

Basically, they have a keyboard that has LEDs and software that allows them to set up rules for the LEDs and they record a video of them playing, and then overlay the resulting software video on top.

Comment: Are such pianos where keys light up common? What's the purpose for that? I'd guess it distracts the performer and adds stress to their eyes.

Comment: [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IZgYViHcXdM) demonstrates what is going on.

Comment: @KevinPanko Thank you. Yeap, as I expected it looks rather distracting.